# sharing html widget to other andoid apps in flutter

Tags: flutter

we have **Html()** widget that renders html content. We also have **Share.share()** that shares given content to other apps. Currently **Share.share()** requires a string as parameter not a widget. So how can i share the well interpreted html content to other applications?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming we're talking about the `Html` widget provided by `flutter_html`.

If you have access to the widget, you can call `.data` on it to get the `String?` value:

```dart
final Html html = Html(data: '<p>Hello world!</p>');

final String stringToShare = html.data;
```

By defining html (the first line) in your build function, you can access it in the share button as well.

Comment: **Error: The getter 'data' isn't defined for the class 'Widget'**

Comment: That might have been because I defined it as a `Widget` on the first line. I changed it to explicitly state `Html`. Are you indeed using the `flutter_html` package? It should work with the code above..